# Regex removing ignore chars

Tags: python, regex

I have regex for finding @usernames in string. I can find the @username but the problem is that it's removing my ignore chars.

What I want:
@username I agree!

What I get:
@usernameI agree!

Code:

```
def rplcheck(match):
    str = match.group(1)

    return '<a href="/medlemmar/%s/" class="user-tag">@%s</a>' % (str.lower(), str)

@register.filter
def usertag(value):
   regex = r'@([\w]+)(?:$|[ ,!?:;.\-<\r\n])'

    p = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)

    value = p.sub(rplcheck, value)

    return value
```

Comment: Have you control over the input string? If so maybe using [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) would be better suited for the task.

Comment: don't use builtin keywords as variable names.

Comment: @Zeeker No, its user generated.

Comment: could you provide an example along with the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a non-capturing group to assert the  end of the string or those characters precede in the string. You can use one capturing group to retain the word characters after `@` ...

```
@(\w+)
```

Also, you can remove the usertag function completely and call it like this.

```
>>> re.sub(r'@(\w+)', rplcheck, text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was overthinking this:

```
regex = r'@([\w]+)(?:$|[ ,!?:;.\-<\r\n])'
```

should be:

```
regex = r'@([\w]+)'
```